# Время жизни сессии в firefox и ie всего 1 минута

Tags: php, сессия

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Если в  firefox и ie бездействовать более 1 минуты, то сессия удаляется (то есть вылетает). Параметр session.gc_maxlifetime у меня 1440. В Хроме и Опере все нормально. Можно это как-то исправить? Спасибо!

Comment: Другие настройки сессии какие? Как id передаёться, где храниться, **cookie_lifetime**?

Comment: session.auto_start(off),session.cache_expire(180),session.cookie_lifetime(600),session.cookie_secure(off),session.gc_maxlifetime(1440),session.use_cookies(on),session.use_only_cookies(off),session.use_trans_sid(off). Открываю сессию Session start() и присваиваю данные пользователя так: $_SESSION["auth_login"] =. Где хранятся cookie_lifetime вообще без понятия, сайт на хостинге. Где-то читал, что это браузер сам разрывает соединение, но это создает большую проблему. Спасибо!